# how to format a uint that's holding a price in ETH on solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

Quick question let say I have product number 1 which its price is declared as 5 eth, is there a way to format it to avoid insering it in Wei on solidity?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to represent values in Wei as much as possible. If you want to input a value into a function in ether and store it in Wei you could do something like this.

```
uint price;

function setPrice(uint amountInEth) public {
    price = amountInEth * 1 ether;
}
```